# xml parsing (Removing parent nodes)

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Hi I'm seriously stuck when trying to filter out my xml document. Here is some example of the contents:

```
<sentence id="1" document_id="Perseus:text:1999.02.0029" >
    <primary>millermo</primary>
    <word id="1" />
    <word id="2" />
    <word id="3" />
    <word id="4" />
</sentence>


<sentence id="2" document_id="Perseus:text:1999.02.0029" >
    <primary>millermo</primary>
    <word id="1" />
    <word id="2" />
    <word id="3" />
    <word id="4" />
    <word id="5" />
    <word id="6" />
    <word id="7" />
    <word id="8" />
</sentence>
```

There are many sentences (Over 3000) but all I want to do is write some code (preferably in java or python) that will go through my xml file and remove all the sentences  which have more than 5 word ids,
 so in other words I will be left with just sentences tags with 5 or less word ids. Thanks. (Just to note my xml isnt great, I get mixed up with nodes/tags/element/ids.

I'm trying this atm but not sure:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('treebank.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
parent_map = dict((c, p) for p in tree.getiterator() for c in p)

iterator = list(root.getiterator('word id'))

for item in iterator:
  old = item.find('word id')
  text = old.text
  if 'id=16' in text:
      parent_map[item].remove(item)
      continue

tree.write('out.xml')
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a tutorial, code-writing, or homework service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an XSLT solution where no looping is required. As information, [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) is a declarative, special purpose language designed natively to transform XML documents to various formatting, styling, structuring for end use purposes. Specifically here, the identity transform copies entire document as is and writes an empty template to all `<word>` nodes whose position is greater than 5.

**XSLT script** *(save as .xsl or .xslt file)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="word[position() &gt; 5]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** Script

```
import os, sys
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML AND XSL
dom = ET.parse('C/Path/To/Input.xml')  
xslt = ET.parse('C/Path/To/XSLTscript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM XML
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

# PRETTY PRINT OUTPUT
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True,  xml_declaration=True)
print(tree_out.decode("utf-8"))

# SAVE TO FILE
xmlfile = open('Output.xml'),'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

And the beauty of XSLT is that it is transferrable as practically all general purpose languages maintain XSLT processors including Java:

**Java Script**

```
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Sentence {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {

        String currentDir = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        String xml = "C:/Path/To/Input.xml";
        String xsl = "C:/Path/To/XSLTScript.xsl";

        // Transformation
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(xsl));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text = new StreamSource(new File(xml));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("C:/Path/To/Output.xml")));

   }

}
```

**OUTPUT** *(using posted content)*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <sentence id="1" document_id="Perseus:text:1999.02.0029">
    <primary>millermo</primary>
    <word id="1"/>
    <word id="2"/>
    <word id="3"/>
    <word id="4"/>
  </sentence>
  <sentence id="2" document_id="Perseus:text:1999.02.0029">
    <primary>millermo</primary>
    <word id="1"/>
    <word id="2"/>
    <word id="3"/>
    <word id="4"/>
    <word id="5"/>
  </sentence>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `word` is a tag and `id` is its attribute; you can't pass them both to `.find()`.
Also, the result of parsing is a tree, where attributes and text are represented differently than in an XML file.

I suppose you have a root element which has `<sentence>` elements as children.
The you have to look at each `<sentence>` node, count its `<word>` elements, and remove the sentence if needed.

```
# We cannot iterate over a tree and modify it at the same time.
# Remember the nodes to remove later.
elements_to_kill = []

for sentence_node in root.getiterator('sentence'):
    if len(sentence_node.findall('word')) <= 5:
        elements_to_kill.append(sentence_node)

# Now it's safe to remove them
for node in elements_to_kill:
    root.remove(node)

# Serialize as file, etc
```

Hope this helps.

You seem to lack the grasp on how ETree works. Please feel free to [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and experiment in a Python REPL to gain the understanding.